# tight asymptotic bounds

Tags: recurrence-relations, recursive-algorithms

I have the below recurrence:

$$T(n, 1) = 3n$$

$$T(1, m) = 3m$$

$$T(n, m) = 3n + T \left( \frac{n}{3}, \frac{m}{3} \right )$$

How to get a tight asymptotic bound for $T(n, n^2)$ assuming that $n$ is an exponent of $3$.
Using substitution method for $T(m,n)$, I get a very weird relation

$$T(n,m) = 3n + \frac{m}{3^{k-1}} +  n \left [ 3 - \frac{1}{3^{k-1}} \right ]$$

Any suggestion would be helpful

Comment: Welcome to MSE! What is $k$ in your "weird relation"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

You might define a new relation $S(p,q) \triangleq T(3^p, 3^q)$.
This gives you a new recurrence:

$$S(p,0) = 3^{p+1}$$
$$S(0,q) = 3^{q+1}$$
$$S(p,q) = 3^{p+1} + S(p-1,q-1)$$

(do you see why?)

After making this change, your case of interest, $T(n,n^2)$, becomes $S(p,2p)$ (do you see why?) and it's quite easy to compute a closed form for this. Notice $p < 2p$, so we know which base case is relevant for us! Then it's just a matter of setting $n = 3^p$ in your closed form for $S(p,2p)$ to get a closed form for $T(n,n^2)$.

As for asymptotics, the closed form you get from the above procedure is so nice I'm not sure you need anything fancier.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Your comment is really confusing. (,2) , becomes (,2) how?

Comment: If $n = 3^p$, then $n^2 = 3^{2p}$.

Comment: then in that case if $n = 3^p$ shouldn't n/3 be $3^{p-1}$. How do you get (−1,−1)?